# Show $\int_0^tK(s) e^{-k(t-s)} \text{d}s\approx K(t)\int_{-\infty}^t e^{-k(t-s)} \text{d}s$ using Watson's lemma

Tags: integration, asymptotics, approximation, approximate-integration

How can you show using Watson's lemma, that for some infinitely differentiable function $K(s)$ and $ kt \gg 1$ that

$$\int_0^tK(s) e^{-k(t-s)} \text{d}s\approx K(t)\int_{-\infty}^t e^{-k(t-s)} \text{d}s$$

Does one say, let us change variables to $u=t-s$

$$\int_0^tK(s) e^{-k(t-s)} \text{d}s = \int_t^0 K(t-u) e^{-ku} (-\text{d} u) \\
= \int_0^t K(t-u) e^{-ku} \text{d}u 
\approx \frac{K(t) \Gamma(1)}{k}  $$
By Watson's lemma as $ kt \gg 1$ and $ k \gg 1$ (the $n=0$ term in the summation of Watson's lemma).

This clearly doesn't work, would someone be able to point out where I have gone wrong here and how I can produce the desired result?

**EDIT**

Something I have tried is

$$\int_0^t K(t-u) e^{-ku} \text{d}u = \int_0^\varepsilon K(t-u) e^{-ku} \text{d}u + O(e^{k\varepsilon})$$

where $1/k\ll \varepsilon \ll 1$. Letting $z=ku$ gives
$$\frac{1}{k}\int_0^{\varepsilon k} K\left(t-\frac{z}{k}\right)e^{-z}\text{d}z
\sim
\frac{K(t)}{k}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-z}\text{d}z$$
as $\varepsilon k \gg 1$ and by making the approximation $K\left(t-\frac{z}{k}\right)\sim K(t)$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$.

Therefore as $z =k(t-s)$ 
$$\int_0^tK(s) e^{-k(t-s)} \text{d}s\approx K(t)\int_{-\infty}^t e^{-k(t-s)} \text{d}s$$

**Question update**

The above method gives the correct result, where then in my original attempt have I made a mistake and specifically what mistake was it?

Note, the definition for Watson's lemma which I used originally is found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma

Comment: Watson's lemma proper does not allow for the case that $t$ varies with $k$, so you will not be able to prove this by only using Watson's lemma. Further, it does not seem to be true without additional restrictions on $t$ or $K$. For example, if $t=k$ and $K(x) = e^{-x^2}$ then $$\int_0^t K(s) e^{-k(t-s)}\,ds \sim \sqrt{\pi} e^{-3k^2/4} \not\sim \frac{K(t)}{k} = K(t) \int_{-\infty}^{t} e^{-k(t-s)}\,ds.$$

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Thank you for this, I think I need to loosen the restriction and allow $k\gg 1$. I will post an edit soon.

Comment: If $t = O(1)$ it might be true, I think.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: This approximation should become more accurate as $t$ increases for my purposes. See new update.

Comment: The approximation $K(t-z/k) \sim K(t)$ seems crucial, since it fails for the counterexample $K(x) = e^{-x^2}$ I mentioned earlier. If that property is characteristic of the functions $K$ you're interested in then your new proposed method may indeed form the base of a proof if you can make it rigorous.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Many thanks for this, however this method I proceeded with is effectively the method of proof for Watson's lemma, however using the definition of it given here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma, as I have in my first attempt seems to fail, i'm unsure as to why!

Comment: Yes, I wrote that proof on wiki :) As I mentioned, it has to do with the fact that you want to allow $t$ to increase with $k$, whereas in the proof on the wiki page it is taken to be constant.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Ah wow! Small world (on mathematics forums..), thank you for your help, I believe this question to be resolved now!

Comment: @AntonioVargas: I will accept my own answer to mark this question as resolved unless you want to post one, in which case I will accept yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^t K(t-u) e^{-ku} \text{d}u = \int_0^\varepsilon K(t-u) e^{-ku} \text{d}u + O(e^{k\varepsilon})$$

where $1/k\ll \varepsilon \ll 1$. Letting $z=ku$ gives
$$\frac{1}{k}\int_0^{\varepsilon k} K\left(t-\frac{z}{k}\right)e^{-z}\text{d}z
\sim
\frac{K(t)}{k}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-z}\text{d}z$$
as $\varepsilon k \gg 1$ and by making the approximation $K\left(t-\frac{z}{k}\right)\sim K(t)$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$.

Therefore as $z =k(t-s)$ 
$$\int_0^tK(s) e^{-k(t-s)} \text{d}s\approx K(t)\int_{-\infty}^t e^{-k(t-s)} \text{d}s$$

This is equivalent to the initial work you did you massive cretin.

Many thanks to Antonio Vargas in pointing this out.